# Strange! linux & windows vsprintf float num to file

Tags: c++, windows, linux, floating-point, printf

use vsprintf to write the content to file.

output format is:

```
"tt2:%f, tt2:%x", tt2, *((int *)&tt2)
```

linux：

```
gcc 4.4.5: -O2 -ffloat-store
```

In linux.in file is like this:

> tt2:30759.**257812**, tt2:46f04e84

windows：

```
vs2005 sp1: /O2 Precise (/fp:precise)
```

In windows. in file is like this:

> tt2:30759.**257813**, tt2:46f04e84

Why that is different?

==================================

I have find the reason for my case.

In windows, I use the ofstream to output to file. It'c c++ lib.

In linux, I just use write to output to file. It's c lib.

When I use ofstream in linux, the output is the same.

After all,  thanks for everyone~

Comment: Different rounding by the different compilers?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Quite possible that it's the C library, not the compiler.

Comment: The exact value here is `30759.2578125`.  Linux is rounding correctly, according to the usual round-ties-to-even rounding mode.  Windows is not.

Comment: @Mark Dickinson: Thanks. Maby, I used differet lib.

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point numbers are stored in the computer in binary. When printing them into decimal floating-point, there are multiple correct representations for them. In your case, both of them are correct, as both of them convert back to the original binary floating-point value. Look at the output of this file, which I compiled using GCC:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 30759.257812f;
    float b = 30759.257813f;

    printf("%x\n%x\n", *(uint32_t *)&a, *(uint32_t *)&b);
}
```

Output:

```
46f04e84
46f04e84
```

Therefore, an implementation of `printf` and friends may choose to display any of the two decimal floating-point numbers.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Is there any way to makesure the output the same use "%f", when the float is the same in memory?

Comment: When converting a floating point number to decimal, there is only one "correct" conversion, depending on the rounding conventions used (which are implementation defined).  (There will be, of course, and infinite number of decimal values which convert to the same floating point number.)

Comment: Does that means the rounding conventions in vs2005 and gcc is defferent, in my case?

Comment: In my case, I proceeed tt2 like this, tt2 = float_floor_5(tt2); float::float_floor_5(float v)
{
    float l_v = v;
    float v_3 = floor(l_v * 100000.0f);
    v_3 = v_3 / 100000.0f;
    return v_3;
}

Comment: @JamesKanze What is your definition of a "correct" conversion? IIRC, the only requirements of a "correct" conversion is to convert back to the original binary floating-point number and to minimize the number of digits. So, I don't see why any of the two representations would be "less" correct than the other.

Comment: @user1202136 The implementation defines what is "correct", but it can't very well require a round trip conversion, since that is impossible.  In general, it will specify the rule it uses when rounding: to even, to zero, away from zero, etc.  But for each rounding convention, there is one (and only one) correct conversion.

Comment: @JamesKanze I'm not sure you can use the term "rounding" in this context. To me "rounding" means reducing the precision of a result to fit in a target register of variable. However, in our case, there is no loss of precision: the target string could be arbitrarily large. There are simply multiple answers (i.e., string representations) that convert back to same floating-point number. What you are actually asking, is for an implementation to return the *smallest* decimal number.

Comment: Regarding correctness of rounding, this appears to be controlled by some version of the C standard. In C 2011, 7.21.6.1 paragraph 13 says the result should be “correctly rounded”, given that the number of significant digits is less than DECIMAL_DIG for the implementation). 3.9 defines “correctly rounded result” as the representation in the result format that is nearest in value. It does not define behavior for ties. This appears to be a shortcoming in the standard, and unfortunately leaves unsupported a claim that rounding 12.5 to 13 is incorrect. Beyond DECIMAL_DIG, more slack is permitted.

Comment: @user1202136 I don't know what else you'd call it.  The standard certainly calls it rounding, and that's what I've seen it called in all of the literature I've seen.  And the implementation cannot generate an arbitrary long target string; what it generates is constrained by the precision argument.  And I'm not asking that the implementation return the smallest decimal number; I'm asking that it return the correct value, using the rules of rounding that it has defined and documented.

Comment: @user1202136: “Rounding” is the term commonly used to refer to selecting one of the numbers representable in a destination format given a source number that may not be exactly representable. In this case, the fixed precision of the output format (“%.f” requires 6 digits after the decimal point) causes only certain numbers to be representable in our destination format (a decimal numeral with 6 digits after the decimal point). A source value that does not equal one of these representable values **must** be changed by the conversion. This is called “rounding” in the standards documents.